Laravel 11 axios API Vue 3 422 Unprocessable Content
When trying to submit a POST request using Axios in Vue to a Laravel API, the validation is running perfectly but at the time checking if the validation fails ($data->fails()) then it returns a JSON response as an error with status 422. It is not going in the next line where a custom return message is written.
I installed package
composer require laravel/breeze --api

I have 2 ports in localhost
For Laravel
http://localhost:8000/

For VUE
http://localhost:8080/

.env
APP_NAME='Laravel'
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:RXw+M7zZjmXJOaBwk8+MGeEHPs23HKza0CcFMTRO+30=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Tehran
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:8080
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

bootstrap/app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->api(prepend: [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        ]);

        $middleware->alias([
            'verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        ]);

        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
            '*',
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

axios.js
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";

main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css'
import 'bootstrap'
import '../axios'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')

Login.vue
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
            <h1 class="lh-lg">Login</h1>
            <form @submit.prevent="submitLogin">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" v-model="form.email">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="password" class="form-label">password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" v-model="form.password">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
const router = useRouter;
const form = ref({
    email: '',
    password: ''
});
const getToken = async () => {
    await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
}
const submitLogin = async () => {
    console.log('Form Value:', form.value);
    await axios.post('/login', {
        email: form.value.email,
        password: form.value.password,
    });
    router.push('/');
}
</script>

error-1
error-2
